# How to modify a path which's in a variable (python)?

Tags: python, path

After finding the path of the Python file which I am actually working on with `os.getcwd()` and `__file__` I want to modify it, so if I put it in a variable named `r` and then delete one part of the path that will be very good. For example, the path is `'C:\\Users\\Shadow\\Desktop\\213.py'` if I want to delete `\\213.py` from the path (`r`) how can I do that?

Comment: This is standard string operations, so what have you tried so far based on your own research?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can manipulate your string:

```
r = 'C:\\Users\\Shadow\\Desktop\\213.py'
r.rsplit('\\', 1)[0]
```

output:

```
'C:\\Users\\Shadow\\Desktop'
```

you may also want to have a look over [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path)

Comment: [0] will return the first element

Answer (score 0):

You extract the directory name in your example. This is easily achieved with `os.path.dirname`.

```py
import os
os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

This solution is cross-platform (mostly), and avoids most pitfalls that arise from treating paths as strings.

If you need the value stored in a variable:

```py
import os
r = on.path.dirname(__file__)
```